# It's too late. / Too late

Tags: sentence-construction

> **It's too late.**
>
> **Too late.**

When is it possible to use "Too late.", or is it not grammatically correct, except titles? What's the difference between the first sentence and the second one in their usage?

Comment: Sergei, this question is too broad. You're asking for a list of all the possible cases where both are correct and incorrect and explanations for each, so I'm closing this to new answers. If you can edit it to be about one specific context, I'll be happy to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Too late!" is an exclamation indicating that the other person has missed their opportunity to do something that would have been useful or helpful.

There is a story about Sir Walter Raleigh spreading his expensive cloak on the ground in front of Queen Elizabeth I to cover a patch of mud. In the film *Shakespeare in Love*, there is a joke about this when the Queen finds a puddle in front of her as she is walking to her coach; she looks at the gentlemen standing nearby, who reluctantly start to unfasten their cloaks. "Too late!" she says, and strides through the puddle anyway.

Comment: What's the difference between the first sentence and the second one in their usage?

Comment: _It's too late_ is just an ordinary statement. "We'd better not disturb him now. It's too late [in the day]." "It's too late to do anything about it now."

Comment: @KateBunting - in poetic speech, drama, or writing we can repeat an utterance, e.g. I cannot speak to my friend because he has died on a sinking ship. It's too late! Too late! Far too late!

Answer (score 0):

When you say *it’s too late*, you’re referring to something that cannot be done due to it being too late, but just saying *too late* is saying directly to someone that it is too late for **them**, and assuming they know what you are talking about.